# Convert the quarter date column with the last day of each quarter to the first day of each quarter, or vice versa

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, zoo

Suppose I have the following `df1` or `df2`, how can I use R to convert the last day of each quarter to the first day of each quarter in `date` column, or vice versa? Thanks.

**df1:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2010-3-31", "2010-6-30", "2010-9-30", 
"2010-12-31", "2011-3-31", "2011-6-30", "2011-9-30", "2011-12-31"
), value = c(24.1, 16.4, 18.5, 8.61, 12.6, 20.1, 17.9, 14.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Out:

```
        date value
1  2010-3-31 24.10
2  2010-6-30 16.40
3  2010-9-30 18.50
4 2010-12-31  8.61
5  2011-3-31 12.60
6  2011-6-30 20.10
7  2011-9-30 17.90
8 2011-12-31 14.50
```

**df2:**

```
df2 <- structure(list(date = c("2010-1-1", "2010-4-1", "2010-7-1", "2010-10-1", 
"2011-1-1", "2011-4-1", "2011-7-1", "2011-10-1"), value = c(24.1, 
16.4, 18.5, 8.61, 12.6, 20.1, 17.9, 14.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Out:

```
      date value
1  2010-1-1 24.10
2  2010-4-1 16.40
3  2010-7-1 18.50
4 2010-10-1  8.61
5  2011-1-1 12.60
6  2011-4-1 20.10
7  2011-7-1 17.90
8 2011-10-1 14.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Converting a yearqtr object to Date class will give the first of the quarter so

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df1 %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(as.yearqtr(as.Date(date))))
```

giving:

```
        date value
1 2010-01-01 24.10
2 2010-04-01 16.40
3 2010-07-01 18.50
4 2010-10-01  8.61
5 2011-01-01 12.60
6 2011-04-01 20.10
7 2011-07-01 17.90
8 2011-10-01 14.50
```

**2)** To get the end of quarter note that `as.Date.yearqtr` has a `frac=` argument which is 0 (default) for beginning of quarter, 1 for end of quarter or any fraction between.

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(as.yearqtr(as.Date(date)), frac = 1))
```

giving:

```
        date value
1 2010-03-31 24.10
2 2010-06-30 16.40
3 2010-09-30 18.50
4 2010-12-31  8.61
5 2011-03-31 12.60
6 2011-06-30 20.10
7 2011-09-30 17.90
8 2011-12-31 14.50
```

**3)** Another possibility is, rather than representing the quarter by a date to represent it directly as a yearqtr object.  yearqtr objects are internally year + 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4 for the 4 quarters so they can be easily manipulated and sorted, e.g. if yq is a yearqtr object yq+1/4 is the quarter following.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(date = as.yearqtr(as.Date(date)))
```

giving:

```
     date value
1 2010 Q1 24.10
2 2010 Q2 16.40
3 2010 Q3 18.50
4 2010 Q4  8.61
5 2011 Q1 12.60
6 2011 Q2 20.10
7 2011 Q3 17.90
8 2011 Q4 14.50
```

Comment: Thanks, how could we convert `date` in `df2` to `df1`?

Comment: Have moved comment to answer.